how to add product to my cart in django rest frame work drf
model
class Cart(models.Model):     
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)     
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)   

class CartItem(models.Model):     
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')     
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cart_items')     
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()      
    
    class Meta:         
       unique_together = ['cart', 'product']

views
class CartItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):     
    http_method_names = ['get','post','patch','delete']     
    serializer_class = CartItemSerializer     
    queryset = CartItem.objects.all()      
    def get_queryset(self):         
        cart_pk = self.kwargs['cart_pk']         
        return CartItem.objects.select_related('product').filter(cart_id = cart_pk).all()     
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):         
        if self.request.method == 'POST':             
            return AddCartItemSerializer         
        elif self.request.method == 'PATCH':             
            return ChangeCartItemSerializer         
        return CartItemSerializer     
    
    def get_serializer_context(self):         
        return {'cart_pk':self.kwargs['cart_pk']}   
    
class CartViewSet(CreateModelMixin,RetrieveModelMixin,DestroyModelMixin,GenericViewSet,):     
    serializer_class = CartSerializer     
    queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related('items__product').all()     
    lookup_value_regex = '\[0-9a-f\]{8}\\-?\[0-9a-f\]{4}\\-?\[0-9a-f\]{4}\\-?\[0-9a-f\]{4}\\-?\[0-9a-f\]{12}'  

serializer
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):     
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, source='name')     
    price = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2,source='unit_price')     
    unit_price_after_tax = serializers.SerializerMethodField()          
    
    class Meta:         
        model = Product         
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'price','category', 'unit_price_after_tax', 'inventory', 'description']          
        
        def create(self, validated_data):         
            product = Product(**validated_data)         
            product.slug = slugify(product.name)         
            product.save()         
            return product     

can any one help me ??
i have
i try searching in internet and ask chat gpt but nothing can you help me

can you please add error details?
